# Mapping hasMany relation and saving the related data

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have two domain classes Question and Tag.
Question has 'hasMany relation' with Tag.

I am trying to save a question with some tags, but the error message is 
"Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.org.Tag for property tag; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.org.Tag] for property tag: no matching editors or conversion strategy found "

from my UI how can i send the list of Tags into QuestionController and how can i save Question with relationship with Tag

Comment: Can you show me what your Question and Tag domains look like? Also your code for saving these domains would be helpful.

Comment: Try adding 'belongsTo' to the 'many' domain class. Also, please add your class/es definition

Answer (score 1):

Your currently having 
    static hasMany = [tags:Tag]

But i believe you might be storing it directly as a string

```
questionInstance.tags = ['tag1', 'tag2',...]
```

as opposed to

```
questionInstance.tags = [new Tag(name: tag1), new Tag(name: tag2),...]
```

I skipped the looping through tag values to show you whats implied. Hope this helps.